# libusbdotnet inf package how to make the inf valid

Tags: c#, libusb-1.0

I'm new to the USB programming. We have a custom hardware that we plug into the computer and send/receive data from it.

I used the USB InfWizard provided by LibUsbDotNet to create the USB inf/setup packages.

I noticed that I couldn't right click on the INF to install it. It shows the following pop-up:
[image]

I had to go to the device manager route to install it. But it shows this pop-up
[image]

So my question is using the driver setup packaged generated by the LibUsbDotNet tool.

What do I need to do to for windows to be able to verify the publisher of the driver?

Do I have to signed or something? What am I missing?